# WordPress Gravatar filter is removing my custom attributes

Tags: php, functions, filters, hooks, gravatar

I am trying to add a `style` attribute on all the custom gravatar images. However, it is removing the `style` attribute before final output. Here is the code I am using:

```
$background = '';
$args = [$background];

function my_custom_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt, $args ) {
  $user = false;

  if ( is_numeric( $id_or_email ) ) {

    $id = (int) $id_or_email;
    $user = get_user_by( 'id' , $id );

  } elseif ( is_object( $id_or_email ) ) {

    if ( ! empty( $id_or_email->user_id ) ) {
        $id = (int) $id_or_email->user_id;
        $user = get_user_by( 'id' , $id );
    }

  } else {
    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $id_or_email );   
  }

  $user_id = $user->user_email;

  $image_hash = md5($user_id);
  $first_color = substr($image_hash, 0, 6);
  list($r, $g, $b) = sscanf($first_color, "%02x%02x%02x");
  $color_inner = "rgba($r, $g, $b, 0.25)";
  $color_outer = "rgba($r, $g, $b, 1)";
  $avatar = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/'.$image_hash.'?d=robohash';
  $args[0] = "background: radial-gradient($color_inner, $color_outer);";
  $avatar = "<img src='{$avatar}' style='{$args[0]}' class='avatar avatar-{$size} photo' height='{$size}' width='{$size}' />";
  // var_dump($avatar);

  return $avatar;
}
add_filter( 'get_avatar' , 'my_custom_avatar' , 1 , 10, 6 );
```

If I uncomment `var_dump($avatar)`, it gives me the following output:

```
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/image_hash?d=robohash" style="background: radial-gradient(rgba(229, 24, 243, 0.25), rgba(229, 24, 243, 1));" class="avatar avatar-64 photo" width="64" height="64">
```

However, the returned value of `$avatar` is:

```
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/image_hash?d=robohash" alt="Comment Author" class="avatar avatar-64 wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-64 photo avatar-default" width="64" height="64">
```

There is no code between `var_dump($avatar)` and `return $avatar`. What is causing this change in returned HTML? How can I get a return avatar with all attributes including `style`?